# How to loop an array in batch and move files

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I have the following:

```
@echo off
set Arr[0]=1234
set Arr[1]=2351
set Arr[2]=4321
set Arr[3]=6106
```

How can I loop in an array? Also at each loop I want to see if a file exists that contains like a wildcard the number of the Array. For example for Arr[0] if there's a file that contains 1234 like ABC_1234.txt or 1234_ABC.txt or 1234.txt then returns true otherwise false.

I'm a complete beginner in batch so any help appreciated.

Comment: Example: `for /F "tokens=1* delims==" do %%I in ('set Arr[ 2^>nul') do if exist "*%%J*" dir "*%%J*" /B` Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `for /?` and `set /?` and `if /?` and `dir /?` and read each output help carefully and completely from top of first to bottom of last page. There are hundreds of batch files posted on Stack Overflow using that __FOR__ loop.

Answer (score 1):

Given your provided example variable value strings, I'd suggest this simple sort of approach. It parses the variable names defined within the environment, via the `Set` command.

```batch-file
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableExtensions

Rem Ensure that there are no existing Arr[n] variables.
For /F "Delims==" %%G In ('2^> NUL Set Arr[') Do Set "%%G="

Rem Define new Arr[n] variables.
Set "Arr[0]=1234"
Set "Arr[1]=2351"
Set "Arr[2]=4321"
Set "Arr[3]=6106"

Rem Loop through the Arr[n] variables.
For /F "Tokens=1,* Delims==" %%G In ('2^> NUL Set Arr[') Do Echo "%%H"

Pause
```

*I've just used `Echo "%%H"` in the loop, you'd obviously replace that with your `If Exist`, `Dir` etc. command to search for the files with respect to those variable value strings.*